# AIML syntax for detecting a keyword present anywhere in a line?

Tags: aiml

Let the keyword be 'course'. I tried * COURSE *,_ COURSE * and various other permutations of this but wasn't getting the desired result.(My line could be anything but definitely has the word course somewhere in it).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this depends if you are using AIML v1 or AIML v2.

For AIML v1, you will need to set up 4 categories. One to detect "course" on its own, one for any input that starts with "course", one for any input that ends with "course" and one  to handle input with "course" inside it:

```
<category>
    <pattern>COURSE</pattern>
    <template>Your input contained the word "course".</template>
</category>

<category>
    <pattern>COURSE *</pattern>
    <template><srai>course</srai></template>
</category>

<category>
    <pattern>_ COURSE</pattern>
    <template><srai>course</srai></template>
</category>

<category>
    <pattern>_ COURSE *</pattern>
    <template><srai>course</srai></template>
</category>
```

The reason you need 4 categories is that the * and _ wildcards match one or more words. However, if you are using AIML v2 (which you should be!), you can do this using # wildcard, which matches zero or more words:

```
<category>
    <pattern># COURSE #</pattern>
    <template>Your input contained the word "course".</template>
</category>
```